# Evaluate $\int_{\Gamma}\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{z}}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Evaluate $$\int_{\Gamma}\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{z}}$$ where $\Gamma$ is the the upper half of the unit circle and $\sqrt[4]{1}=1$

$\Gamma(t)=e^{it}$,  $0\leq t \leq \pi$

$\Gamma'(t)=ie^{it}dt$

$$\int_{\Gamma}\frac{ie^{it}dt}{\sqrt[4]{e^{it}}}$$

Now

$$\sqrt[4]{e^{it}}=e^{\frac{1}{4}log{e^{it}}}=e^{\frac{1}{4}i(t+2\pi k)}$$

Now it is given that $\sqrt[4]{1}=1$ so:

$$\sqrt[4]{1}=1=e^{i0}=e^{\frac{1}{4}i(t+2\pi k)}$$

So $$t+2\pi k=0$$?

How do I know which $k$ from $\{0,1,2,3\}$ should I take?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From $e^{0 i} = 1 = \sqrt[4]{1} = e^{2\pi i k/4}$ we know that $ \frac{\pi k}{2}$ needs to be an integer multiple of $2\pi$. For $k \in \{ 0,1,2,3\}$ this is only possible for $k=0$.

Comment: so cos will be $cos(0+2\pi k)=1$?

Comment: $\cos(0 + 2\pi k) = 1$ holds for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ since $\cos$ is $2\pi$-periodic.